# Using Two GPUs (Radeon+Nvidia)

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, graphics, gpu

I have a `Radeon Vega 64` on a machine primarily used for computing, but have a collection of problems with the output graphics (freezes, mouse selection problem, etc). I tried all available AMD drivers, but still not reliable.

I decided to buy a cheap Nvidia GPU like `GTX 9xx` for video output and use the AMD GPU only for computing tasks.

1. Can I use two GPU independently for different tasks?
2. How should I set up the system to avoid any conflict or problem?

Note that I am not talking about SLI here. I just don't want to give up the computing power of Vega 64.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it.

If your computational program supports AMD OpenCL, then typically you can select a device or it will default to your AMD card.

However, as far as I know, games use the card with the monitor plugged into it. I think it is only possible with SLI or Crossfire.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. There is no gaming activity on this machine.